# Using an automator variable in Applescript

Tags: variables, applescript, automator

I want to use an Automator variable in Applescript (inside of Automator) but I didn't find any info online on how to do it. [This is my Automator project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNLAL.png), and here is the Applescript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete file Path
    empty trash
end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automator is scriptable, so in a workflow you can just use its terms, for example:

```
set thePath to value of variable "Path" of front workflow
tell application "Finder"
    delete file thePath
    empty trash
end tell
```

Note that `path` is a parameter name, so I used a different variable name for it in the script.

---

Another option is to use `Get Value of Variable` and pass it on to the `Run AppleScript` action, for example:

- **Ask for Text**
- **Set Value of Variable** {Variable: Testing}
- -- other workflow stuff --
- **Get Value of Variable** {Variable: Testing} (Ignore Input)
- **Run AppleScript**

  ```
  on run {input, parameters} -- input is from the previous action
     set theValue to (first item of input) as number -- input is always a list
     if theValue > 1 then display dialog "It works!"
     -- return item(s) to the next action as needed
  end run
  ```

Comment: how would I go about this if I would use a number instead of a path, since  `as number` isn't working with automator variables, at least for me.

Comment: It works for me.  What exactly is the contents of the variable?

Comment: imgur.com/gallery/eXyz6Pk I hope the link works.

Comment: I just manually set the variable for testing, but it looks like Rich Text from the text action isn't getting coerced (Automator is just goofy that way).  A way to fix that is to add a default `Run Shell Script` action (passing input as arguments) after getting the text and before `Set Value of Variable` (I am guessing the `Get` action in your link was supposed to be a `Set`).  Another option would be to `Get Value of Variable` and pass it to the `Run AppleScript` action.  I’ve edited my answer to add that.